# can't figure out how to put the text in the table (playfair cipher)

Tags: python

```
table =
    [['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
     ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
     ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
     ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
     ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*']]

def print_table():
    for row in range(5):
        for col in range(5):
             print table[row][col],
    print ""

def clear_table():
    for row in range(5):
        for col in range(5):
        table[row][col] = "*"

def table_has_letter(letter):
    for letter in clear_table:
        if letter in clear_table:
            print true
        else:
            print false
```

## this is were i think i went wrong

have to use module (%)

```
def create_table(secret):
    clear_table()
    secret = secret.upper()
    secret.replace(" ","")
    secret.split(",")
    for col in range(5):
        row = 1
        if len(secret) % 5: 
           row += 1
        print [len(secret) % 5]
        print secret[col]

create_table("mathematics")
print_table()
```

This is the what is expected:

```
 P L A Y F
 A I R * *
 * * * * *
 * * * * *
 * * * * *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to modify:

```
def print_table():
    for row in range(5):
        for col in range(5):
             print table[row][col],
        print  # Added so it print new lines
```

And your create_table should be something like:

```
def create_table(secret):
    clear_table()
    secret = secret.upper()
    secret = secret.replace(" ",'')
    secret.split(",")
    row = 0
    col = 0
    for i in range(len(secret)):
        if  i != 0 and i % 5 == 0:
            row += 1
            col = 0
        table[row][col] = secret[i]
        col += 1
```

**Testing:**

```
create_table("Hi world")
print_table()
>>> 
H I W O R
L D * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *

create_table("play fair")
print_table()
>>>
P L A Y F
A I R * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
```

**Edit**

To remove duplicated letters, use this method:

```
def removeDup(mystring):
    newStr = ""
    for ch in mystring:
        if ch not in newStr:
            newStr = newStr + ch
    return newStr
```

And add it to your `create_table` method.

```
def create_table_without_rep(secret):
    clear_table()
    secret = secret.upper()
    secret = secret.replace(" ",'')
    secret.split(",")
    row = 0
    col = 0
    secret = removeDup(secret) # Add this line     
    for i in range(len(secret)):
        if  i != 0 and i % 5 == 0:
            row += 1
            col = 0
        table[row][col] = secret[i]
        col += 1
```

Comment: what if u don't want a letter to repeat

Comment: Could you give an input-output example?

Comment: its the same but for the example for play fair. you the second A does not appear, so the second line would be  I R * * * the rest is the same